# Why is gradle overriding AndroidManifest.xml wrongly?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-manifest

I'm using the support-v4 library in an android studio project with gradle.

In my `app` directory, the build.gradle file has this code:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 20
}....
```

When I try to build this project, the AndroidManifest.xml inside the support-v4 directory (in /build/...) gets updated and it's `uses-sdk` tag becomes:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="L"
    android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

I then get this message:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1`

Why is this happening and how can get my project to build while keeping config in build.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that perhaps the newest version of the support library (which I had as a dependency) has issues.

I fixed this issue by changing the support-v4 version in the build.gradle dependencies from:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20'
```

Comment: Remember to update every other + to 20 too. Like the appcompat, etc.

Comment: Do you know why I'd have to do this?

Comment: not entirely sure, but i believe 21 onwards requires at least version L, so changing it back will allow you to have a lower min sdk version? probably something in the sdk version 4.21 onwards..